# How can I add custom script just for Master layout page in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have an Admin panel which has sidebar menus. It acts as a Master Layout page. I inserted some `@section` in the Master admin panel for child page's content and scripts. (I know the structure of Layout pages and child pages and I have used it several times.)
But I have a question. 
I have used Ajax in the content pages. Then in the child page's script section, starts with:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
```

The problem is Here : Now I want to use Ajax in Master layout page, then I should add some custom script for the Admin panel which has to start with:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
```

If I add this code to Master Layout page, It will be duplicated.
What should I do ?

Comment: Thenk you all. Actually I got the meaning of Layout page and content pages. My fault was that I thought that a layout page is a real page and now I got that it is just a layout and dont have and real code and script.

Answer (score 0):

In your layouts page, where you have the layouts, you need to add a `@yield('scripts')` below the js scripts, especially below the jquery script.

Then, in your current page, add this below all the contents,

```
@section('scripts')
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     // some stuff here
  })
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: It means that in master page ,I will have some thing like this : 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){....
</script>
@yield('scripts')  
Is it ok ?
@AntonyMN

Comment: No ... in the master page, just below your other scripts, add `@yield('scripts')` same way you add `@yield('content')` and leave it as is

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply some custom scripts only on admin page, you could share your script with current view you want, and do something like this in your admin controller:

```
$scripts[] = '/dist/js/admin/shop.js';
view()->share('scripts', $scripts);
```

To include these custom scripts, in your main blade component, check if you passed any scripts. If you did, they will be included in your layout:

```
@if(isset($scripts))
    @foreach($scripts as $key => $value)
        <script src="{{ asset($value)}}"></script>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Actually I didnot get your answer. Maybe my question was so Vague. The thing that I want is using Ajax for master page and child page. In chaild page I use it without any problem. And now I want to use it for Master page seperately. (for loading child page without refresh all content). and this needs again ajax and I dont know where I should insert this script in the master page .@zlatan

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. Actually I got the meaning of Layout page and content pages. My fault was that I thought that a layout page is a real page and now I got that it is just a layout and don't have and real code and script.